# How to force a file system check on the next boot of the root file system on Gentoo running systemd?

Tags: systemd, gentoo, fsck

I want to force a fsck run on my root filessystem on my Gentoo system running systemd.

I've tried

- adding an empty `forcefsck` file at the root of the filesystem which I want to check, e.g. `touch /forcefsck`
- adding `fsck.mode=force` as kernel boot parameter

Nothing worked so far. What's the right approach?

Comment: I would recommend to explore /etc/inittab which can give you control for the next boot.<Thanks>

Comment: So changing the boot configuration twice has been exchanged for changing the fstab twice.... Intercepting the boot in the bootloader, then enter editing the command line and adding the parameter(s) for the boot en boot doesn't change any config (permanently).
Should be easy to do with grub involved.

Answer (score 2):

The latter (`fsck.mode=force`) is the right approach. However, to fsck a root, you must either:

- have a systemd-controlled initramfs (so that it could parse `fsck.mode=force`) with the corresponding fsck binary built in;
- have an initramfs which mounts rootfs read-only (so that systemd, started from rootfs, still can check it — checking a read-write mounted filesystem is impossible);
- have no initramfs and tell kernel to mount rootfs read-only (by `ro` kernel cmdline parameter).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what worked for me was ignore what is written on blogs and go read the man page. Having to change your boot configuration twice for simply forcing a check of your root partition did not sound right.

You specify `passno=1` in your `/etc/fstab` for the filesystems you would like to check and reboot. Simply remove the entry after reboot.

The [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fsck@.service.html)